# Trying to open a file from command line

Tags: c++, command-line

So i wanted to write some code that work like `type` in command line
meaning when I write the text file name it displays the content of it.
I wrote this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *t;
    t = fopen(argv[1], "r");        // tring to open file from command line
    if (t == NULL){
        cout << "the file doesnt exists\n";
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        fseek(t, 0, SEEK_END);
        int size = ftell(t);
        fseek(t, 0, SEEK_SET);

        char* x = new char[size];

        fread(x, size, 1, t); 

        for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
        {
            cout << x[i];

        }


        delete[] x;
    }




      return 0;
  }
```

**I got Debug Assertion Failed Error**

```
Exppression:file!=NULL <br>
```

Comment: It's a good idea to check you have enough arguments before you try to use them. To use `argv[1]`, `argc > 1` must be true.

Comment: That was exactly what was wrong with it. @InternetAussie

Comment: What is "Exppression"? I find it hard to believe that this is really the message you got.

Comment: @Arof: Why would you expect it to work without actually giving it the filename? Strange question!

Comment: yeah because someone would lie about messages, believe it or not that is what i got and who the hell pissed in your coffee i obviously gave it the file name before posting this question!!!! @BoundaryImposition

Comment: I do respect the work you do here and your knowledge though.@BoundaryImposition

Comment: Clearly you passed a file pointer that was NULL. That's what is causing the assertion to fail; it expects a non-NULL pointer. When you get an assertion triggered like this, it breaks into the debugger. You then look at the call stack to go back to *your* code and figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: @Arof: Then why is `argv[1]` empty? And what tool emits the misspelt "Exppression" please so that I can raise a bug with its author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before using arguments from `argv`, make sure that there are enough for your needs:

```
if (argc > 1) {
    // We have enough args in argv, go for it
    t = fopen(argv[1], "r");
} else {
    /* do something else that doesn't need argv[1] i.e. ask the user */
}
```